# Selecting img from a tree of classes

Tags: css

Struggling to change the size of an image.

```
<div class="mypage">
<div class="mypage-block">
<div class="mypage-image">
<a href="/mylink">
<img alt="" src="mypic.jpg" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;"></a></div>
```

This is what I have tried

```
.page .page-block .page-image img {
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
}
```

When I inspect in Chrome it shows this img value as "element.style" set at 180px, this is the value I am having problems overriding.

Comment: Remove the inline styling...it will normallty win as it comes after the CSS sheet.

Comment: Inline styling has higher priority than css file, remove it and you should be just fine :)

Comment: Use !important to your new css img.

like:     

`.page .page-block .page-image img {    
width: 140px !important;    
height: 140px !important;   
}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline styling...it will normally win as it comes after the CSS sheet as it will therefore have priority.

If **absolutely** necessary you can force the stylesheet to 'win' by adding `!important` statements but it's not recommended.

```css
img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-180-180-5.jpg" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;" alt="">

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-180-180-5.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

The inline style on the img element is overriding your CSS styling.

In order to undo this (assuming you have no ability to remove the inline style from the img element itself) you need to add an !important deceleration to your CSS attributes.

Your classes in your CSS file also do not match up those declared in your HTML

```
.mypage .mypage-block .mypage-image img {
width: 140px !important;
height: 140px !important;
}
```